# when build on IOS 14 cannot find CFBundleVersion

Tags: flutter, ios14

My Info.plist code is like below

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

so I think it shoud get CFBundleVersion with $(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER) value.
however If I build app I get error

```
The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a CFBundleVersion.
```

Should I modify Flutter build number value as 1.0.0 for example?
Is there any way that it can get these number by themselves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The bundle's Info.plist does not contain a CFBundleVersion key or its value is not a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111501/the-bundles-info-plist-does-not-contain-a-cfbundleversion-key-or-its-value-is-n)

Comment: I saw that too. But what I want to know is if it is the only solution typing manually the CFBundleVersion.

Comment: did you find a solution?