# Nativescript - The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript-cli

**Describe the bug**

When I build and run my apps on tns cli or directly in xcode, i have the error:

```
Unable to apply changes on device: 2727B173-9A43-43B3-A51E-4D3CAC1E3EF9. Error is: Command xcrun with arguments simctl install 2727B173-9A43-43B3-A51E-4D3CAC1E3EF9 /Users/user189510/Documents/poly3000-nativescript/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/poly3000nativescript.app failed with exit code 22. Error output:
 An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion.
```

The info.plist in App_Resources/IOS seems ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>fr</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>YaToYa</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.3.1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
<key>UseExternalPushProvider</key>
<true/>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have check in Xcode if value was correct (yes), clean simulator, delete cache from xcode, try to restart all the process after deleted all, deleted folder Developer/DerivedData in xcode... but always the issue.

I have try a lot of proposition find on the web without success.

Some people to help me please?

**To Reproduce**

Prepare the application to run on simulator:

tns clean
tns prepare ios
tns run ios

**Expected behavior**

Start the application on ios simulator

Comment: Did you check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356969/466577
If you added recently a whole folder, you may try it.
There are other suggestions there as well - like cleaning the project, etc.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @AhmedAhmedov

The project is not created in XCode but with NativeScript, and NativeScript create the XCode projet. Perhaps the issue is in the project creation... I investigate on this.

I have already clean the project, the cache and all possible cleaning i think.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!!!

I have found the issue, a bad format of the file.
The correct file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>fr</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.3.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UseExternalPushProvider</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The question can be close.

Thanks