# React Native App throwing domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=3 Error

Tags: xcode, react-native

I've updated quite a few NPM packages in my React Native app and now even though it seems to build fine, it starts and immediately crashes on the iOS simulator. The error that it throws is:

> Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered
> processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain,
> code=3) The request to open "org.reactjs.native.example.myappname"
> failed. THe process did launch, but has since exited or crashed.

Prior to these npm package updates, the app was running fine. I found a few suggestions such as running `rm -rf ios/build`, cleaning the project, etc. I tried all these but still getting the same error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
BTW, this is a `react-native: "^0.65.1"` app and the Xcode version is 12.4.

Comment: Did you try 1) updating your Xcode to 12.5 or newer? 2) building the app to your iPhone device instead of the simulator? 3) Building using Xcode instead of the command line? 4) In Info.plist, change CFBundleIdentifier from $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) to any hard coded value 5) Use a different bundleId 6) Use a different simulator device (iPhone 8s,..)

Comment: Everyone else seems to be suggesting updating to Xcode >= 12.5, but I think I know why you're on 12.4. You're likely on Catalina, like me.

Plain `react-native` 0.65 builds and runs fine for me though, so currently I suspect maybe some of your `npm` packages may be conflicting with the updated react native version, causing the simulator to crash immediately.

That's just a theory though. I think it might help if we're able to see your package.json or package-lock.json

Comment: were you able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

If there is no recent change in the iOS project files then try:

1. **Reset Content and Settings of the simulator**:

[image]

2. If reseting the simulator content and settings doesn't work, **update Xcode to its latest version**.

Answer (score 1):

The error was thrown in my case because of the bundle id was copy pasted to xCode and it had space around:

```
" com.your.app "
```

instead of

```
"com.your.app"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when I run my project on a new M2pro mac.

Installing rosseta worked:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

run this command on terminal

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while upgrading a React Native application and found the actual error a few lines above:

`An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22): Failed to install the requested application The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleShortVersionString. Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleShortVersionString.`

Then a few lines later `error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=4):`

[Fixing the above error by setting the version correctly in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111501/the-bundles-info-plist-does-not-contain-a-cfbundleversion-key-or-its-value-is-n) fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was for xml formatter and when I formatted the file it was added " " before package name.
check the source after formatting the file.

Comment: in which file you incurred this error?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I hope it helps you too
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error, just by hardcoding my bundle identifier

Bundle Identifier: org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME)

I replaced bundle identifier value with **com.xyz**

where PRODUCT_NAME = xyz