# How to solve the "The Bundle Identifier could not be determined" error?

Tags: flutter

While trying to run our Flutter app, we get an error that says:

"The Bundle Identifier could not be determined"

In Info.plist, `CFBundleIdentifier` is set to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`

What could be the problem here?

Flutter version: 2.10.1
Xcode version: 13.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved it by erasing all content and settings of the Simulator.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56575496/6753606) answer.