# CFBundleVersion is not recognized in info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I'm working on a project and when I wanted to get latitude and longtitude, I needed to add info.plist.
with the same code base, I added info.plist but I got the following error

**The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion. Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion**

I cannot figure out why xcode keeps asking me for CFBundleVersion though it's present in info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Example</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.********</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Hello, Application wants to use your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Hello, Application wants to use your location</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Hello, Application wants to use your location</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

any idea ?

I tried the solutions in the post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111501/the-bundles-info-plist-does-not-contain-a-cfbundleversion-key-or-its-value-is-n), but none of them worked out for me

Comment: Check your target's Build Settings and whether the "Info.plist File" build setting is pointing to the correct file.

Comment: What is the filename you used? is it really `info.plist` (lowercase)?